# SwiftUI GeometryReader does not layout custom subviews in center

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader

I have a custom view:

```
struct ImageContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("smile")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }
}
```

Which is being placed into another view with a `GeometryReader`:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ImageContent()
        //Image("smile").resizable().scaledToFit()
    }
}
```

The problem is, the `ImageContent` view is not centered on the screen, it is being placed on the top, however, by removing the `ImageContent` subview and directly adding the view's content into the geometry reader will fix the issue (see picture).

Also, removing the `GeometryReader` can fix the issue as well.

I need the subview because I will be implementing some additional logic, and also need the `GeometryReader` because there is a gesture added to the `Image` that uses it.

Any idea?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @Asperi okay, I'm not too familiar with GeometryReader. Let me edit that out... The question still stands though, if there are any fix/workaround.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Update: retested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

Try the following (built-in container by default expanded to size of GeometryReader and have explicit default alignment set to center by both dimensions). Tested with Xcode 11.2.

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
       VStack { // explicit container with center default alignment
        ImageContent()
       }
       .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear DEV, reading this, ensure you do not use ZStack as the container; it will not work. Use VSack and next ZStack in it.

Answer (score 46):

I'm not sure why this is happening but you can use what others have suggested, or use the `midX` and `midY` from `GeometryProxy`'s frame. Like the following:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ImageContent()
        .position(x: geometry.frame(in: .local).midX, y: geometry.frame(in: .local).midY)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use the `GeometryProxy` value passed inside your `GeometryReader` body.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ImageContent()
                .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

This will define the exact position based on value provided.

Answer (score 14):

I just ran into the same problem and I don't like the solution of setting the position manually because it complicates the process of automatically generating layout. For me the problem persists even after wrapping my content in a VStack. However, if you wrap the content in a VStack AND also manually set its frame - everything works as expected:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
       VStack {
        ImageContent()
       }
       .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
    }
}
```

I think this issue pops up because GeometryReader's internal layout acts like a ZStack and it needs more information.

Comment: Can set `frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` instead

Comment: I liked this solution a little more since I'm not sure in all cases I want the frame set to infinity, I like it being locked to the size GeometryReader initially found.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had a similar issue with the contents of a `GeometryReader` not being aligned to the center.
It seems that the default behaviour has been changed somewhat recently from center to upper-left corner alignment.

The answers provided here did not work for me, so here's one which should be universal:

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        ZStack {
            /* the views which you want to have aligned
               not to the upper left corner go in this method */
            contentView(geo)
        }
        .frame(
            width: geo.size.width, 
            height: geo.size.height, 
            alignment: .center
        )
    }
}

func contentView(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
    VStack {
        // views
    }
    .frame(
        width: proxy.size.width * 0.5, // you can, for example, use the GeometryProxy size directly here
        height: proxy.size.height * 0.5,
        alignment: .center
    )
}
```

I've used the snippet provided above to create a popup which is half the container view's size and is aligned to the center.
Use it as a starting point in creating any layout you wish inside a `GeometryReader` in a clean and manageable way.