# GeometryReader seems to change layout of view that is using its size data. How can I avoid this?

Tags: swift, layout, swiftui, geometryreader

I would like my icon image to be 1/3 the width of total screen availability. My code is as follows:

```
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Image(systemName: "square.dashed").resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width/3)
        }
    }
```

When I do this, the icon shows up in the upper left of the screen, it doesn't remain in the center like I would have thought.  For example, this works properly but is not dynamic based on screen size

```
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "square.dashed").resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(maxWidth: 200)
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is possible solution (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

```
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        Image(systemName: "square.dashed").resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width/3)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
```

Comment: This works fine for simple cases, but did not work for me. I've posted a universal solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77797397/4444684

Answer (score 1):

> If you ever want to center a view inside a GeometryReader, rather than aligning to the top-left corner, add a second frame that makes it fill the full space of the container, like this:

```
GeometryReader { geo in
Image("Example")
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.8)
    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
```

}

> from:
> https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/resizing-images-to-fit-the-screen-using-geometryreader

Comment: I've tried it and it did not work. Although, just to learn something new about SwiftUI, could you explain how and why setting the `.frame` would work in this case or in general?